# How to apply spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings configuration property to all consumers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-kafka

I was able to apply **partition.assignment.strategy** for single channel using the following property in **application.properties**:

**spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.configuration.partition.assignment.strategy**

This is according to https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_kafka_consumer_properties

What I want to achieve is to apply **partition.assignment.strategy** for all channels with a single property and avoid writing the same thing for all channels.

Tried setting **spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration** but it didn't help.

Maybe anyone knows how to achieve this?

**Additional info:** I'm using Spring Cloud 1.3.2.RELEASE.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I edited my answer I just tested it and it works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested it and it works fine for me...

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.partition.assignment.strategy=\
    org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor
```

with

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class So49053074Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So49053074Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void in(byte[] in) {

    }

}
```

and

```
2018-03-01 11:01:28.301  INFO 46708 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    ...
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, your simple example works as expected. spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration seems to be working in that simple example but for some reason it does not work on our service that is way more complicated :)  Will try to find why... Let me know if you have any idea what might cause this.

Comment: Weird. I can't think of any reason why the complexity would make a difference.